# Is @ symbol allowed in naming a file?

Tags: php, file

Is it okay to have filename with @ symbol.? 
Will it be accepted in all operating systems.

I'm using uploadfilename@timestamp.extension.

BTW, I'm using php to create file

Comment: Belongs on SO I would say.

Comment: macOS and *nix allow you to create. Remember to use '\@' to access to file.

Comment: @AndreaGirardi: Thanks, I didnt know we need to escape @ for mac os.

Comment: @gnat I got the answer and I accepted it. If you find this question is not useful, you can vote to close. Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about limitations of file systems, but does not provide enough information to identify which filesystems are under consideration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I'm sure there are [some arcane system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_operating_systems) that does not allow '@' in file names.

But '@' is certainly allowed on all current versions of Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.